# Single ajax request to update 2 different <DIV>

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Is it possible to update 2 different targeted DIV simultaneously using 1 ajax?

Let say I have *index.html* below:

```
<script>
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("main_body").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;}
                                                 }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","some_page.php",true);
      xmlhttp.send();
</script>

<div id="main_body">
<div id="update_1"></div>
<div id="dont_ajax">A big size of html content....</div>
<div id="update_2"></div>
</div>
```

In above case, all I know is the *some_page.php* has to be written like below:

```
<php
     echo "<div id="update_1"><h1>Apple</h1></div>
           <div id="dont_ajax">A big size of html content....</div>
           <div id="update_2"><h1>Orange</h1></div>";
?>
```

I don't want the *some_page.php* to load the content of id="dont_ajax" due to its large html content. I am looking for some kind of solution like:

```
<script>
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("update_1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText(1);
        document.getElementById("update_2").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText(2);}
                                             }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","some_page.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
</script>

<div id="main_body">
<div id="update_1"></div>
<div id="dont_ajax">A big size of html content....</div>
<div id="update_2"></div>
</div>
```

so  that the some_page.php can be as simple as:

```
<php
 echo "<h1>Apple</h1>"; //(become respondtext(1))

 echo "<h1>Orange</h1>"; //(become respondtext(2))
?>
```

I know my example above won't work, I just want to show you the problem and what I want to achieve. Pls  give me some ideas, thanks. Or if u have other way to achieve this, pls suggest.

*I need solution in native JS.*

Comment: Well the first problem is your php will have syntax errors due to not back flashing the double quotes in the strings you want to echo....

Comment: Ok noted. Do u have any solution to my problem?

Comment: no, response should be one but... why don't you respond with the array like:

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can update any number of elements.
It depends on the way you're preparing and parsing your response.

This code is awful as ajax response has only one responseText:

```
<php
 echo "<h1>Apple</h1>"; //(become respondtext(1))
 echo "<h1>Orange</h1>"; //(become respondtext(2))
?>
```

You'll receive `<h1>Apple</h1><h1>Orange</h1>` in the response and you'll produce more ugly code trying to split it in parts.

The best solution is preparing JSON string:

```
<php
 echo "{update_1: '<h1>Apple</h1>', update_2: '<h1>Orange</h1>'}";
?>
```

Then parsing the response and updating the document:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
   var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
   ['update_1', 'update_2'].forEach(function(i){
      document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = data[i];
   });
}
```